# Schedule a future post to a Facebook group

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, schedule, facebook-group

I'm trying to post a link to a facebook group:

```
$post_url = '/' . $my_group_id . '/feed';
$post_params = array('link' => $link, 'message' => $message)
$postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $post_params);
```

This works great. Now I try to schedule this post to some future time.
So I add the parameter:

```
'scheduled_publish_time' => strtotime($schedule),
```

And now I get one of two errors. If I don't add anything more, I get
*"(#100) You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post"*
And if I add the parameter:

```
'published' => false
```

then I get
*"(#200) Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself."*

However, this is a **group**, not a page, and to the best of my knowledge I cannot "post as the group itself", or can I?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that based on the current design (as per 27-Oct-2013), I doubt there is any schedule for posting to group. The schedule is for page only.